# wlan is first brought to life when ethernet is plugged in

Tags: linux, debian, networking, wifi

```
    Endless timeouts...
    Request timed out.
    Request timed out.
    Request timed out.
    Request timed out.
    Request timed out.
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time=105ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
    Request timed out.
    Request timed out.
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time=105ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time=71ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time=61ms TTL=64
    Reply from 192.168.1.11: bytes=32 time=87ms TTL=64
```

I'm having a small problem with my debian box (not running any gnome/kde...). I can get the wireless to work, but only if I connect the ethernet cable in for a second or two.

Above is my ping result from my workmachine. I turned off the debian box, started the ping and turned the debian box on. I got a endlessly Request timed out untill i plugged in the ethernet. I've then removed the the ethernet cable (the two time outs in the middle there). Wireless is still up after ethernet is removed and I can putty my way in.

I'm using `auto wlan0` but I've also tried `allow-hotplug` :-( /etc/network/interfaces)

Comment: Please post the complete contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` and anything else network-related that you've configured. Are you also running Network Manager or some such?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing more of your `/etc/network/interfaces`, I can only hope my working example helps you:

`/etc/network/interfaces` regarding `wlan0`:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-driver wext
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

# known networks
iface default inet dhcp
```

with `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` a list of wireless networks I occasionally use, e.g.

```
network={
        ssid="network1"
        key_mgmt=NONE
}
network={
        ssid="this-other-one"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        psk="wassport"
}
```

Now if there's a known network to connect to, the `ifup` mechanism will start a DHCP client process on the interface after connecting successfully.

See `/usr/share/doc/ifupdown/examples` for more working examples and a lot more information.